# Ionic 4 - Ionic Input Two-Way Binding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In Ionic 4 how do you do two-way binding. In Ionic 3 I would do the following:

```
<ion-item color="light"> <ion-input type="string" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input> </ion-item>
```

However in Ionic 4 I get the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("d>
          <ion-item color="light">
              <ion-input type="string" placeholder="Username" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item color="light">
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginPage.html@12:62
```

How do I get this working in Ionic 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please keep in mind to add the FormsModule to your module or create a SharedModule to import and export FormsModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import **FormsModule** in **app.module.ts**.
As i have already gave the answer in detail.
Visit to the link for detail 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684045/7983887

Answer (score 0):

Add FormsModule in the your Angular module