# My [(ngModel)] is not working in the custom component in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working in my Ionic 4 project and I have created a custom component but in that custom component my `[(ngModel)]` is not working.

This is my **custom-header-component.component.html:**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="languageSelected" (ionChange)='setLanguage()' ngDefaultControl>
    <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="ar">Arabic</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In this html my `[(ngModel)]` is not working because it is not printing any value in the console.

This is my **custom-header-component.component.ts:**

```
languageSelected: any;
setLanguage() {
let me=this;
console.log('languageSelected',me.languageSelected);
}
```

In this ts file, it is not printing any value.

Maybe the problem is that, I have not included the `FormsModule`.

This is my **Folder:**

```
custom-header-component:
|
-- custom-header-component.component.html
-- custom-header-component.component.scss
-- custom-header-component.component.spec.ts
-- custom-header-component.component.ts

components.module.ts
```

This is my **components.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomHeaderComponentComponent } from './custom-header-component/custom-header-component.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomHeaderComponentComponent],
    exports: [CustomHeaderComponentComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    imports: [
     FormsModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
})
export class ComponentsModule{}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you have not included `FormsModule` then you should get error in console and add `FormsModule` in imports array

Comment: @ashishpal. Okay but in which file, I have to import.

Comment: in your module.ts

Comment: @ashishpal. For this I dont have the module.ts file.

Comment: in `components.module.ts` add `imports: [FormsModule]` and import it from `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: @ashishpal. I have imported but it is showing error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute.

Comment: @ashishpal. I have added the <ion-select [(ngModel)]="languageSelected" (ionChange)='setLanguage()' ngDefaultControl> but the error is gone but it is not showing any value in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191836/discussion-between-ashish-pal-and-rahul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **`<ion-option`**

```
 <ion-option value="en">English</ion-option>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-sample?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

EDIT:

If it's ionic 4 ,your code looks correct. As mentioned in the question if you have not included **`FormsModule`**  you need to add it as

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Sir, I am using Ionic 4.

Comment: This is not working. I have added this in my app.module.ts.

Comment: I have imported it to my components.module.ts also.

Comment: can you produce on stackblitz?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the selected value in this without ngModel

Answer (score 5):

you just need to import **FormsModule** in  **app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and add **ComponentPage** inside **declarations** and **entryComponents**

You can see the example below

In **app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ComponentPage } from './component/component.page'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ComponentPage,
 ],
entryComponents: [
   ComponentPage,
  ],
  imports: [FormsModule],

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<ion-select ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="languageSelected" (ionChange)='setLanguage($event)'>
    <ion-select-option value='en' [selected]="language==='en' ? true : null">English</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value='ar' [selected]="language==='ar' ? true : null">Arabic</ion-select-option>
</ion-select> 

 setLanguage($event) {
    let me=this;
   console.log('Default language:', $event.target.value);
  }
```

In this, You can get the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not placing your ion-select inside a form tag, you'll need to set the name attribute. If you are not placing it inside a form tag, the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions. Like this example for a search bar.

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="UpdateSearchResults($event)" [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.input" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-searchbar>
```

This works fine for me in Ionic 4.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure to add CustomHeaderComponent to your declarations array in app.module.ts

Like so:
**app.module.ts**

```
declarations: [...other components, CustomHeaderComponent]
```